# Parsing HTML using LXML Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse Oxford Dictionary in order to obtain the etymology of a given word.

```
class SkipException (Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
try:
    doc = lxml.html.parse(urlopen('https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/%s' % "good"))
except SkipException:
    doc = ''
if doc:
    table = []
    trs = doc.xpath("//div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/section[5]/div/p")
```

I cannot seem to work out how to obtain the string of text I need. I know I lack some lines of code in the ones I have copied but I don't know how HTML nor LXML fully works. I would much appreciate if someone could provide me with the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do web scraping, and especially when probably every dictionary has an API interface.  In the case of Oxford create an account at https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/.  Get the API credentials from your account and do something like this:

```
import requests
import json

api_base = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/{}/{}'
language = 'en'
word = 'parachute'

headers = {
    'app_id': '',
    'app_key': ''
}

url = api_base.format(language, word)
reply = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if reply.ok:
    reply_dict = json.loads(reply.text)
    results = reply_dict.get('results')
    if results:
        headword = results[0]
        entries = headword.get('lexicalEntries')[0].get('entries')
        if entries:
            entry = entries[0]
            senses = entry.get('senses')
            if senses:
                sense = senses[0]
                print(sense.get('short_definitions'))
```

Comment: The problem with this API is that it only lets you search 60 words per minute and 10,000 a month, which for what I want to do, isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample to get you started scraping Oxford dictionary pages:

```
import lxml.html as lh
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parachute'
html = urlopen(url)
root = lh.parse(html)
body = root.find("body")
elements = body.xpath("//span[@class='ind']")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

To find the correct search string you need to format the html so you can see the structure.  I used the html formatter at https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html.  Looking at the formatted HTML, I could see the definitions were in the span elements with the 'ind' class attribute.